# How to create a multiple users in Bintami PostgreSQL

Tags: postgresql, kubernetes, bitnami, helm3

I'm just wondering if there is any possibility to create multiple custom users with Bitnami PostgreSQL helm chart?

Can `auth.username` be used in values.yaml to create multiple custom users? How to assign passwords to users in this case?

Answer (score 1):

I have not tried it myself, but the Bitanmi PostgreSQL helm chart has a section that allows you to run an initdb script. I belleve, you can use it to define additional users.

See here: https://github.com/bitnami/charts/tree/main/bitnami/postgresql#initialize-a-fresh-instance

Let us know if it worked :-)

Comment: Thank you! We already use `primary.initdb.scriptsSecret` in production, but it still remains unsafe, because of k8s Secrets nature and base64 decoding.